# combinatorics - how many ways can I add/subtract 1 from 4 40 times and reach zero without dropping below

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I start at 4 and can add 1 or subtract 1 forty times and I need to 0 without dropping below 0.
tried to start with a Catalan number and add 4 subs but there are too many ways to get the same answers like this. I really need help

Comment: Does "I need to 0" mean the overall sum is supposed to be zero?  Or can we add +1 forty times?

Answer (score 4):

It is equivalent to count reverse sequences which start at $0$ and end at $4$ which are never negative. This is exactly the [ties allowed variant of Bertrand's ballot problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed), so the answer is
$$
\frac{22-18+1}{22+1}\binom{40}{18}.
$$

Comment: Confirmed by [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fIuqRmQph75IJxtK_r56LDgFMLx1CTjC7EcmicmmOGw/edit?usp=sharing). Answer in cell $E41$.

Comment: This assumes you are supposed to end at zero, which may be the intent of "I need to 0".  Otherwise,  adding +1 forty times should be counted as well and everything in between..

Answer (score 2):

For minimum effort, I would make a spreadsheet.  Leaving A blank, label columns $0$ through $44$.  Leaving row 1 blank, in column A put $0$ through $40$.  The rows are the number of $1$s added, the columns are the sums so far, and the entries are the number of ways to get that sum with that many $1$s.  In the column with $4$ and row with $0$ put $1$ because there is $1$ way to get a sum of $4$ with no $1$s.  In each cell except the $0$ column put =(up left)+(up right) because you can get there from either of those cells with the right sign on one more $1$.  In the $0$ column you just put =(up right) because you can't come from a sum of $-1$.  Copy right and down.  The top rows will be Pascal's triangle until the zero restriction comes in.  Sum the entries in the row labeled $40$ and you are done.

Comment: the problems is that i need to show my work, i need an equation or fomula or something, not just the number

Comment: So show the spreadsheet and describe how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The generating function is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{s,n}x^n=\frac1x\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x}\right)^{\large s+1}\tag1
$$
where $b_{s,n}$ is the number of paths of length $n$ with non-negative partial sums that total to $s$.

Here, $s=4$ and $\left[x^{40}\right]\frac1x\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x}\right)^5=24647883000$.

---

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124622), it is shown that
$$
\omega(n)=a_{0,n}=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\tag2
$$
where $a_{s,n}=b_{2s,2n}$.

Note that for $n\ge1$,
$$
b_{0,n}=b_{1,n-1}\tag3
$$
since to return to $(0,n)$ the prior state must be $(1,n-1)$. Furthermore, for $n,s\ge1$,
$$
b_{s,n}=b_{s-1,n-1}+b_{s+1,n-1}\tag4
$$
since to get to $(s,n)$ the prior state must have been $(s-1,n-1)$ or $(s+1,n-1)$.

Applying $(3)$ and $(4)$ a couple of times, we get
$$
a_{0,n+1}=a_{0,n}+a_{1,n}\tag5
$$
and for $s\ge1$,
$$
a_{s,n+1}=a_{s-1,n}+2a_{s,n}+a_{s+1,n}\tag6
$$
Applying $(5)$ to $(2)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
a_{1,n}
&=a_{0,n+1}-a_{0,n}\\[6pt]
&=\frac1{n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}-\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\\
&=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+2)(n+1)n}\binom{2n}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{(n+1)n}\binom{2n}{n+1}\\
&=\frac3{n+2}\binom{2n}{n+1}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
**Lemma:**
$$
a_{s,n}=\frac{2s+1}{n+s+1}\binom{2n}{n+s}\tag8
$$
**Proof:** Induction on $s$.

$(8)$ is satisfied by $(2)$ and $(7)$. Now all we need to do is to show that $(8)$ satisfies $(6)$.
$$
\begin{align}
&a_{s+1,n}+2a_{s,n}+a_{s-1,n}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2s+3}{n+s+2}\binom{2n}{n+s+1}+\frac{4s+2}{n+s+1}\binom{2n}{n+s}+\frac{2s-1}{n+s}\binom{2n}{n+s-1}\\
&=\frac{2s+3}{n+s+2}\frac{(n-s+1)(n-s)}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\binom{2n+2}{n+s+1}\\
&+\frac{4s+2}{n+s+1}\frac{(n-s+1)(n+s+1)}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\binom{2n+2}{n+s+1}\\
&+\frac{2s-1}{n+s}\frac{(n+s+1)(n+s)}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\binom{2n+2}{n+s+1}\\
&=\frac{2s+1}{n+s+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+s+1}\\[6pt]
&=a_{s,n+1}\tag9
\end{align}
$$
$\large\square$

**Corollary**
$$
b_{s,n}=\frac{s+1}{\frac{n+s}2+1}\binom{n}{\frac{n+s}2}\,[2\mid n+s]\tag{10}
$$
**Proof:** The Lemma proves the case for even $n$ and $s$. We simply need to apply $(4)$ to the Lemma to prove the case for odd $n$ and $s$:
$$
\begin{align}
b_{2s+1,2n+1}
&=b_{2s,2n}+b_{2s+2,2n}\\[6pt]
&=a_{s,n}+a_{s+1,n}\\
&=\frac{2s+1}{n+s+1}\binom{2n}{n+s}+\frac{2s+3}{n+s+2}\binom{2n}{n+s+1}\\
&=\frac{2s+1}{n+s+1}\frac{n+s+1}{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n+s+1}+\frac{2s+3}{n+s+2}\frac{n-s}{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n+s+1}\\
&=\frac{2s+2}{n+s+2}\binom{2n+1}{n+s+1}\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
$\large\square$

In this case, $b_{4,40}=a_{2,20}=\frac{5}{23}\binom{40}{22}=24647883000$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, consider $n$ negative steps and $m$ positive steps with $n \ge m$ and starting out at the integer $n - m$, and count the 'good' paths that don't dip into the negative integers. We want to show that the good paths, represented by $[n,m]$, is given by

$$\tag 1 [n,m] = \frac{n-m+1}{n+1} \binom{n+m}{n}$$

It turns out that the base case are precisely the Catalan numbers, since the formula when $n = m$ is the number $C_n$ (see this Catalan theory [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3179610/432081)).

We are going to prove $\text{(1)}$ using the method of infinite descent.

Assume that $\text{(1)}$ doesn't hold for some integers. Select $m$ to be minimal, and it so it must be greater than $1$. With $m$ chosen, select $n$ to be minimal when working under $m$. Using Catalan theory, we must have $n \gt m$.

We have  $[n,m] = [n-1, m] + [n, m-1]$ and by the minimality conditions,

$$\tag 2  [n-1, m] =  \frac{n-1-m+1}{n} \binom{n-1+m}{n-1}$$

$$\tag 3  [n, m-1] =  \frac{n-m+2}{n+1} \binom{n+m-1}{n}$$

if we can show that adding $\text(2)$ and $\text(3)$ together gives the RHS of $\text(1)$ we will have a contradiction. But the proof is found in the accepted answer at

[Proving an algebraic binomial identity related to Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180213/proving-an-algebraic-binomial-identity-related-to-bertrands-ballot-theorem)