# Proving an algebraic binomial identity related to Bertrand's ballot theorem

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, catalan-numbers

I am trying to answer the math.stackexchange question found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171065/combinatorics-how-many-ways-can-i-add-subtract-1-from-4-40-times-and-reach-zer) by developing all the theory from scratch and not using Bertrand's ballot theorem. My logic boils down to being able to prove the following identity:

$$ \frac{n-m+1}{n+1} \binom{n+m}{n}  =  \frac{n-m}{n} \binom{n+m-1}{n-1} +  \frac{n-m+2}{n+1} \binom{n+m-1}{n}$$

where $0 < m < n$.

I tried using Wolfram but not an expert (or a subscriber). I thought of multiplying both sides to clear the denominator and see what happens, but it seems a bit daunting.

So I post the problem here hoping that 'cranking it out' doesn't involve too many algebraic/binomial tricks of the trade.

Comment: Write all the binomial coefficients as ratios of factorials, and compare. You probably need $0 < m$ and $0 < n$ only, not $m < n$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Looking at the answer $n \gt 1$ should take care of things,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we just need to simplify the right hand side:

\begin{align}
RHS &= \frac{n-1-m+1}{n} {n+m-1 \choose n-1} + \frac{n-m+2}{n+1} {n+m-1 \choose n} \\
&= \frac{n-m}{n} \frac{(n+m-1) !}{(n-1)! m!} + \frac{n-m+2}{n+1} \frac{(n+m-1) !}{n! (m-1)!} \\
&= \Big[\frac{n-m}{n+m} + \frac{(n-m+2)m}{(n+1)(n+m)}\Big] {n+m \choose n}
\end{align}

So now we just need to show the following equality:
$$ \frac{n-m+1}{n+1} = \frac{n-m}{n+m} + \frac{(n-m+2)m}{(n+1)(n+m)}$$

The right hand side can be written as:

\begin{align}
\frac{n-m}{n+m} + \frac{(n-m+2)m}{(n+1)(n+m)} &= 
\frac{(n-m)(n+1) + (n-m+2)m}{(n+m)(n+1)} \\
&= \frac{n^2+n+m-m^2}{(n+m)(n+1)}\\
&= \frac{(n+m)(n-m+1)}{(n+m)(n+1)}\\
&= \frac{n-m+1}{n+1}\\
\end{align}

Which gives you the result.

Comment: I put your logic to work. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3180285/432081

Comment: Thanks for the reference (: