# Calculating walks above the x axis

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

Calculate the number of walks from $(0,0)$ to $(\mathit{n},0)$ where $\mathit{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, that stay above the x axis.

Steps of +1 or -1 for clarification

I came across this question recently and decided to have a go at it myself. However, I've come to a bit of a standstill. I believe the question will use the ballot theorem but I've always had issues applying the ballot theorem to anything apart from a ballot example! In regards to what I have done thus far, it is not much in honesty as I am quite stumped by this question. If someone could give some explanations as to how to solve the question, or suggest resources that would help, I would be very grateful.

Comment: There'll be infinitely many walks unless an upper bound on number of steps is stated.

Comment: The very recent [MSE question 3142969](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3142969) "How to count with Catalan numbers" answers your question.